# Trying to open and close a webpage about 400 times.(VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to open and close a web page over and over again to finish this challenge, i tried using process.start, however when i put in the url it says system cannot find the file specified. I think im probably doing something wrong.

This is my code

```
    For x = 1 To 400
        Using myProcess As Process = New Process
            Process.Start("MY LINK")
            Thread.Sleep(10)
            myProcess.Kill()
        End Using
    Next

    Process.Start("MY LINK")
```

Comment: Is the challenge actually a disguised DDoS attempt?

Comment: No, thought that does sound cool, Its like i have to be the 1000th visitor and it changes each time i open the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is broken - you make a New Process, then you use the static Process.Start, which ignores your new process and instead makes and starts another new process, then you try and kill and dispose the process you never started

If you want a working code that starts a process, hit up [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) for Process - it kinda looks (from variable names etc) like you copied from there to start with, but then put other stuff in that meant the logic from MSDN was broken. Note that if you're starting a URL you'll need to have UseShellExecute as true

```
    Public Shared Sub Main()

        'do this once, then loop it if you think it's a good idea
        Try
            Using myProcess As New Process()

                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True

                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "http://example.com"

                myProcess.Start()

                Thread.Sleep(5000)

                myProcess.Kill()

            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine((e.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Consider also that 10 ms isn't enough time for a process to start and begin to request a page - heck, the windows clock can't even measure 10ms (it's precise to about 16ms) - it's a really short timescale!

You'd be better off [using the WebClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) to download the page 400 times